# You don't have permission to access this resource Python webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape a website and when I am doing that I am getting below output.
Is there a way I can scrape this website?

```
url = "https://www.mustang6g.com/forums/threads/pre-collision-alert-system.132807/"

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Output of the above code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">

<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access this resource.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: anonymous13 - many thanks for your request of help - many thanks for sharing your idea and for the idea exchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The website server expected a header to be passed:

```py
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '\
           'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '\
           'Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36'}

URL = 'https://www.mustang6g.com/forums/threads/pre-collision-alert-system.132807/'


httpx = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

print(httpx.text)
```

By passing header, we told the server that we are Mozilla:)

Comment: Prayson -- many thanks for your idea and the answer - many thanks for sharing your idea and for the idea exchange. The code worked for us.

Comment: Pleasure to have helped.

Comment: Hi! I tried this, but still get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`


My code:

`headers =  {'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://mx.investing.com/commodities/real-time-futures'
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, features="xml")
soup
table1 = soup.find('table', id='cross_rate_1')
table1


headers = []
for i in table1.find_all('th'):
 title = i.text
 headers.append(title)`